# Pandas dataframe: convert column to number with default value

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I'm surprised I couldn't find anything about this:

**Q: How can I convert values of a column to numbers with a default value if casting fails.**

I need all values to be numbers in order to perform arithmetical functions on them. The raw input data contains non-convertible values like `""`,`"**"`, `"not available"`, ....

E.g.

```
1
2
*
4
```

Should become:

```
1
2
0
4
```

What I've tried:

- `to_numberic`: Does not allow to set a default value. `errors=coerce` will set the value to `NaN`, which can not be handled arithmetically afterwards.
- `df[COLUMN].apply (makeNumber)` with `def makeNumber(value): return 0.0` does apparently nothing on the string values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no missing values in original use:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

If need downcast like comment solution:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast="infer")
print (df)
   col
0    1
1    2
2    0
3    4
```

If possible missing values in original and need not replace them:

```
print (df)
   col
0    1
1    2
2    *
3    4
4  NaN

s = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')

df['col'] = s.mask(s.isna() & df['col'].notna(), 0)
print (df)
   col
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  0.0
3  4.0
4  NaN
```

Comment: the second part is very nice +1 (could probably simplify to `m = df['col'].notna() ; <change col> ; s.mask(m, 0)`)